# How to set a different Look & Feel for a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, look-and-feel

Is it possible to set different L&F to specific component (in my case `JTable`) than is already used? If so, how to do it?

Edit: I wrote this piece of code according to this [tutorial](http://jasperpotts.com/blog/2008/08/skinning-a-slider-with-nimbus). Why is this code not working? No fails or exceptions, but `JTable` is still the same.

```
NimbusLookAndFeel nb = new NimbusLookAndFeel();
jTable1.putClientProperty("Windows.Overrides",nb.getDefaults());
jTable1.putClientProperty("Windows.Overrides.InheritDefaults",false);
```

Comment: You could try using the setUI(...) method of the table.

Comment: I tried but I can't figure out what i should put as an argument to set UI to "Nimbus".

Comment: why? LAFs are not meant for mixing, even if you succeeded the outcome most likely will be visually garbled ... (@camickr - better not a) the table will not update itself completely b) there's global LAF state the component might rely on)

Comment: Haven't solved it yet. Seems to be impossible :) but I'm still waiting for suggestions.

Comment: @kleopatra, I know its not a good idea, but people seem to like to do these crazy things so I point them in the direction and let them discover for themselves that its a bad idea. People tend not to listen to our words of wisdom until they prove it for themselves it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the below URL for all UI default values for nimbus look and feel

http://jasperpotts.com/blogfiles/nimbusdefaults/nimbus.html

Go to Table section and use all the those Table component specific UI default values in your application. That should do the trick for you.

Comment: NimbusLookAndFeel nb = new NimbusLookAndFeel();       jTable1.putClientProperty("Windows.Overrides",nb.getDefaults());        jTable1.putClientProperty("Windows.Overrides.InheritDefaults",false); why is this code not working? no fails or exceptions, but jtable is still the same...

Comment: http://www.jasperpotts.com/blog/2008/08/skinning-a-slider-with-nimbus I wrote this piece of code according to tutorial

Comment: @user1091733: To display code, please edit your question where it will be more readable; an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful, too.

Comment: @paulhudson how am I supposed to use them? how to implement? I've tried with the code above but not working...

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to apply the Nimbus L&F to a button, then you simply need to figure out which class that is responsible for rendering Nimbus buttons. The process is just the same as if you want to apply your very own custom L&F, where you set your own UI class on the button.

Comment: @user1091733 It won't be in the API docs for Java, you'll have to look through the documentation for Nimbus itself, or go through its .jar.

Comment: Can't find even documentatin :)

Answer (score 1):

One trick you could do is create a dummy application that uses the Nimbus look and feel, create a `JTable`, and do something like

```
System.out.println (myTable.getUI ().getClass ().getName ());
```

At that point you will know which UI object is used to render the `JTable` when using the Nimbus LAF. You can use this class name when calling `setUI (TableUI)` on your `JTable`:

```
myTable.setUI (new ui_manager_class_name ());
```

As others have said, this is hardly something we recommend though. LAF's are usually meant to be used as a whole package rather than a mix of 2-3 LAF's. Your other way out could be to use the [`MultiLookAndFeel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/multi/MultiLookAndFeel.html), but I have never used it, so I'm not sure it does fulfill your needs. You should read the associated [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/multi/doc-files/multi_tsc.html) if you want to use it correctly.